# How to get pack of value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get pack of value using javascript ?

When load page i want to alert `0-1` value of checkbox that checked

http://jsfiddle.net/3AaAx/94/

```
var cboxes = document.getElementsByName('mailId[]');
var len = cboxes.length;
var pack_value = '';
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if(cboxes[i].checked != false)
    {
        //alert(cboxes[i].value);
        pack_value .= cboxes[i].value+"-";
    }
    alert(pack_value);
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3AaAx/95/

Comment: @madalin ivascu - please answer i'll mark answer thank ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You where using the php (`.`) concatenation not javacript(`+`)

```
var cboxes = document.getElementsByName('mailId[]');
var len = cboxes.length;
var pack_value = '';
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if(cboxes[i].checked != false)
    {
        //alert(cboxes[i].value);
        pack_value+=cboxes[i].value+"-";
    }
    alert(pack_value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear about the question. What I understood is you want to show all the checkbox index number which are checked.

You need to remove "." after pack_value.

here is the solution:

```
var cboxes = document.getElementsByName('mailId[]');
var len = cboxes.length;
var pack_value = '';
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    if(cboxes[i].checked != false)
    {
        pack_value += pack_value === '' ? cboxes[i].value : '-'+cboxes[i].value; 
    }
}
 alert(pack_value);
```